# Retrieving data from firebase returning NULL

Tags: java, android, firebase

When I call listPost(), it will return NULL. I guess it doesn't wait for the listener to fetch the post from the firebase. How can I wait to fetch the post from firebase before arrayPost get returned?

```
public Post[] listPost() {
    ArrayList<Post> list = new ArrayList<Post>();

    // Fetch post from firebase
    postRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot child : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                String id = child.getKey();
                String title = child.child("title").getValue().toString();
                String content = child.child("content").getValue().toString();
                String date = child.child("date").getValue().toString();
                String status = child.child("status").getValue().toString();

                Post post = new Post();
                post.setId(id);
                post.setTitle(title);
                post.setContent(content);
                post.setDate(date);
                post.setStatus(status);
                list.add(post);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError error) {
            System.out.println("The read failed: " + error.getMessage());
        }
    });

    // Convert ArrayList to Array 
    Post[] arrayPost = new Post[list.size()]; 
    list.toArray(arrayPost);
    return arrayPost;
}
```

Comment: In general (this is not Firebase-specific) you can just wait for the operation to finish using some combination of Java's `Object.wait` and `Object.notify` methods. I can't quickly find a good example right now, so hope this is enough to get you started until somebody provides an answer.

Comment: Hi there! Please [read the Java/Android guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/), which covers basic 101 fundamentals like reading data and using the event callbacks.

Answer (score 3):

While you can certainly turn `listPost()` into a synchronous method using something like semaphores, this is not the way Firebase is intended to work. For example, every time you call `addValueEventListener()` it will add a new listener which will be called whenever your data changes, once for every time you called `listPost()`.

If the purpose of the `listPost()` method is to update some state somewhere (e.g. your UI), you can instead update the state directly from your `onDataChanged()` method. This will ensure that you only add one value event listener and updates in your data will always be reflected in your current state without needing to refresh.

```
// Setup once when your app loads
postRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        ArrayList<Post> list = new ArrayList<Post>();
        for(DataSnapshot child : snapshot.getChildren()) {
            String id = child.getKey();
            String title = child.child("title").getValue().toString();
            String content = child.child("content").getValue().toString();
            String date = child.child("date").getValue().toString();
            String status = child.child("status").getValue().toString();

            Post post = new Post();
            post.setId(id);
            post.setTitle(title);
            post.setContent(content);
            post.setDate(date);
            post.setStatus(status);
            list.add(post);
        }
        // Do something with your list of posts here
        updateSomething(list);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError error) {
        System.out.println("The read failed: " + error.getMessage());
    }
});
```

Since you have a list of children here you can also use a `ChildEventListener` here instead and react to child added, child changed and child removed events to update your state or UI.